# Delete the uploaded file in a C# database

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, dao

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select id, Name from FileControl";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        byte[] bytes;
        string fileName, contentType;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select Name, Data, ContentType from FileControl where id=@id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];
                    contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
                    fileName = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    protected void View(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"image/jpg\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
        embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
        embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
        embed += "</object>";
        ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?Id="), id);
    }
    protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        byte[] bytes;
        string fileName, contentType;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete Name, Data, ContentType from FileControl where id=@id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];
                    contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
                    fileName = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                }

                con.Close();
            }

        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/ProfileChange.aspx");
    }
}
```

Here the view and download functionality are working perfectly. I need to delete the uploaded file. The problem is that I am not using any folder to store the files - I am directly using a database to store the paths of the files.
Please help me with correcting the delete functionality.

Comment: You can't post a bunch of code and say, "fix it." What's the problem? What have you done to try and fix it?

Comment: AFAIK, TSQL `Delete` does not return records, so I would use `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead.  Also, if you aren't getting any exceptions, then the problem isn't with how the TSQL statement is written, but most likely the value of the `@id` parameter.

Comment: If you want to delete a file on a file system, you'll need code that actually tries to delete a file on a file system, and not just a record in a database that has a path to the file in the file system.

Comment: His question does clearly state the problem and also clearly states he is NOT trying to delete a file on the file system, he is storing bytes in a Sql Column

Comment: ernest i am unable to post multiple codes here else i would have let u know about what all i have tried...

Answer (score 1):

The `DeleteFile` method has the correct SQL command to delete a record from table `FileControl` by id.

The problem with the `DeleteFile` method is that it is copied, pasted and renamed version of method `DownloadFile` and `DownloadFile` has a SQL query that returns data so it can covert a FileBlob or bytes column `FileControl.Data` into a file with this code:

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];
                contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["Name"].ToString();
            }
```

You have the same code in `DeleteFile` but the SQL statement will return no data, you are deleting a record in DeleteFile and you need to fix this code in `DeleteFile` with `ExecuteNonQuery()` as @ErikPhilips stated in a comment